# Apache2 wildcard subdomains on server with multiple sites

Tags: apache-2.2, wildcard-subdomain

I have an Apache server with multiple sites using their own domains. For one of those sites I wish to have wildcard subdomains.

I have set up the domain records for `*.example.com` and it works just fine.

With this I can configure any subdomain (e.g. `abc.example.com`) to point to any site, as long as I specify the subdomain name.

The wildcard domain though (`*.example.com`) ends up on the site that is configured in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` instead of the site that has `ServerName *.example.com`.

What did I do wrong?

***.example.com**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *.example.com
    ServerAlias abc.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
    <Directory /var/www/example>
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**default**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName default.com
    ServerAlias www.default.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/default/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/default/>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching the ServerName / ServerAlias-directives like this:

```
ServerName abc.example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

As far as I know, wildcards only work with the ServerAlias directive.